# Detect zsh KEYMAP mode for Vi Visual mode

Tags: shell, zsh, vi, prompt

Zsh uses the `zle` function to check the status of the prompt.

There is the `KEYMAP` variable that is supposed to hold certain values according to the Vi mode you are using.

It works fine for `INSERT` and `COMMAND` mode, but I can't get the trigger for the `VISUAL` mode.

From the Zsh manual:

> 18.2 Keymaps
>
> A keymap in ZLE contains a set of bindings between key sequences and
>   ZLE commands. The empty key sequence cannot be bound.
>
> There can be any number of keymaps at any time, and each keymap has
>   one or more names. If all of a keymap’s names are deleted, it
>   disappears. bindkey can be used to manipulate keymap names.
>
> Initially, there are eight keymaps:
>
> emacs EMACS emulation
>
> viins vi emulation - insert mode
>
> vicmd vi emulation - command mode
>
> viopp vi emulation - operator pending
>
> visual vi emulation - selection active
>
> isearch incremental search mode
>
> command read a command name
>
> .safe fallback keymap

I tried the following:

```
function zle-keymap-select {
    echo $KEYMAP
}
zle -N zle-keymap-select
```

But the output keeps changing between `vicmd` and `main` and there is no output when I press `v` to enter visual mode.

Comment: Visual mode is not a single state in zsh: it's defined by the combination of the mark being set, region being active and vi command mode. You can change those states independently with a custom widget or with emacs widgets.

viopp and visual are only ever used as local keymaps with vicmd remaining the selected keymap. This means you don't need to repeat many vi style bindings across three keymaps: bindings in vicmd are shared, Note how few bindings visual and viopp contain compared to vicmd. But it also means that they are never selected triggering the callback.

Comment: I use [this](https://github.com/alfredodeza/zsh-plugins/blob/master/vi/zle_vi_visual.zsh) to get a visual mode keymap called vivis. Might be what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to use additional zsh plugins, you can use this small code piece to detect INSERT, NORMAL, VISUAL, V-LINE and REPLACE modes:

```
case "${KEYMAP}" in
    vicmd)
        case "${REGION_ACTIVE}" in
            1)
                VI_KEYMAP="VISUAL"
                ;;
            2)
                VI_KEYMAP="V-LINE"
                ;;
            *)
                VI_KEYMAP="NORMAL"
                ;;
        esac
        ;;
    viins|main)
        if [[ "${ZLE_STATE}" == *overwrite* ]]; then
            VI_KEYMAP="REPLACE"
        else
            VI_KEYMAP="INSERT"
        fi
        ;;
esac
```

You can add a line pre-redraw hook to update the PROMPT string every time the key map changes:

```
autoload -U add-zle-hook-widget

function line_pre_redraw {
    local previous_vi_keymap="${VI_KEYMAP}"

    case "${KEYMAP}" in
        vicmd)
            case "${REGION_ACTIVE}" in
                1)
                    VI_KEYMAP="VISUAL"
                    ;;
                2)
                    VI_KEYMAP="V-LINE"
                    ;;
                *)
                    VI_KEYMAP="NORMAL"
                    ;;
            esac
            ;;
        viins|main)
            if [[ "${ZLE_STATE}" == *overwrite* ]]; then
                VI_KEYMAP="REPLACE"
            else
                VI_KEYMAP="INSERT"
            fi
            ;;
    esac

    if [[ "${VI_KEYMAP}" != "${previous_vi_keymap}" ]]; then
        zle reset-prompt
    fi

}
add-zle-hook-widget zle-line-pre-redraw line_pre_redraw
```

See my zsh theme for a full example with changing cursor shapes and a prompt mode indicator: https://github.com/IngoMeyer441/steeef.